# Android listview display

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-listview

Hope you are well,

I'm new with android java so i need your help please.

I have a probleme with androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

First onCreate layout it's good and we have no problem :

[Here is the rendering of the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XpOV.jpg)

When i scroll in **listview** look what happen (the **item** of list show on the **tablayout**) :

[Here is the messed up rendering of the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeQQZ.jpg)

This is the xml of layout :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bWonDeal"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Conclue"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorDealDone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bLostDeal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/DealDone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bLostDeal"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Perdue"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorDealPerdue"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/DealDone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/topbackground"></ImageView>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabsDealDetail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bWonDeal"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Timeline" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Détails" />
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconDealEtat"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tTitreOffre"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_users" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_detail_offre"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabsDealDetail"></ListView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarTimeline"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progressmain"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/DealDone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/DealDone"
        android:layout_width="416dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:background="#e3f9ec"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tTitreOffre">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lEtapeCycle"
            android:layout_width="307dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="58dp"
            android:text="Etape de cycle de vente"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="Opportunité détail"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView9"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView9" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lCommercialOffre"
        android:layout_width="265dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="Commercial"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView12"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tTitreOffre" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tTitreOffre"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Titre de l'opportunité"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tMontantDeal"
        android:layout_width="189dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="2000 $"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/DealDone" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listviewtimeline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabsDealDetail" />

    <com.devlomi.record_view.RecordButton
        android:id="@+id/record_button_deal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/recv_bg_mic"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:mic_icon="@drawable/recv_ic_mic_white" />

    <com.devlomi.record_view.RecordView
        android:id="@+id/record_view_deal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:counter_time_color="#ff0000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:slide_to_cancel_arrow="@drawable/recv_ic_arrow"
        app:slide_to_cancel_arrow_color="#000000"
        app:slide_to_cancel_bounds="8dp"
        app:slide_to_cancel_margin_right="10dp"
        app:slide_to_cancel_text="Slide To Cancel" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/optionDealMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="55"
        fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
        fab:menu_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
        fab:menu_colorPressed="@color/colorDealPerdue"
        fab:menu_colorRipple="#99d4d4d4"
        fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
        fab:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
        fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333"
        fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444"
        fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66efecec"
        fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
        fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
        fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
        fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
        fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
        fab:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_position="left"
        fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
        fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
        fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
        fab:menu_labels_textColor="#f2f1f1"
        fab:menu_labels_textSize="15sp"
        fab:menu_openDirection="up"
        fab:menu_shadowColor="#FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
        fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
        fab:menu_shadowYOffset="4dp"
        fab:menu_showShadow="true"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/bOptionAddNote"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_note_add_24px"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="#FFFFFF"
            fab:fab_label="Ajouter une note"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/bOptionAddAudio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_mic_24px"
            app:iconTint="@android:color/white"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="#FFFFFF"
            fab:fab_label="Enregistrement vocal"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/bOptionAddFichier"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_cloud_upload_24px"
            app:iconTint="@android:color/white"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="#FFFFFF"
            fab:fab_label="Télécharger un fichier"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />
    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have RecyclerView and ListView both at the same place in your layout?

Comment: when i click on tablayout i hide the first and show the second

Answer (score 0):

Your `ListView` should scroll underneath your tab layout. you have to add an `elevation` to your `TabLayout`.

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabsDealDetail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:elevation="2dp" <---here
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bWonDeal"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText">
```

Also a personal suggestion `ListView` is not memory efficient, use `RelcyclerView` instead.

Comment: thanks it works but now it show on buttons and textview

Comment: i thnik i found the probleme : when i add xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" on the top it give the probleme. any solution ?

Comment: `xmlns` is just  a tag to refer to the name space of your  xml validation. that tag should be added only on your parent layout and not on the children. Also  you can define just one named `app` like you did  and change every occurrence of `fab` to `app`.

Comment: try the same trick or change  your layout structure. Also please mark the answer as accepted if that solved your original question.

Comment: thanks for your support but i can't find the solution :( after many test i found that when i add com.devlomi.record_view.RecordButton from https://github.com/3llomi/RecordView in my layout i found this problem

Comment: Can you answer your question listing how is that solving your problem?

Comment: when i will found a solution, i will post here.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly, i found a solution :

i create 2 constraintlayout first have android:elevation="2dp"
 and the second i add elevation to 2 items (RecordView and RecordButton) with 16dp, and it work :D